# How can i write the text of my String array into multiple Textboxes

Tags: c#, forms

i want to know how i can write the text of my String Array in multiple textboxes. For example i have an array of the length 5 so it should write inside the first five textboxes the text that is stored. [The maximum is 14 textboxes that can be written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPhch.png)  The string is filled with filenames that i read out of the given path and i want to display every filename in an textbox so the user can select which one he wants to use.

Comment: do you mean automatically create the textboxes?

Comment: I already created the textboxes. I just want to go like an loop from textbox1 to textbox(lenght of the array) and write the value that is stored in the array.

Comment: Or if its easier to create the textboxes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. But if you want to "connect" the text of a Textbox with a variable in the .cs code you can use ```<Textbox Text="{Binding variable[i}"```in the xaml file, where variable is your array and i your index. I hope to be proved helpful

Comment: he is using winform, not wpf.

Comment: Should i maybe store the each Textboxes in an Array aswell and then call each textbox out of it

Comment: oh ok...so Binding not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the user to select a line of text, i would recommend to use a ListBox.
The array should also be a List of strings.

The List for string would look like that:

```
List<string> texts = new List<string>();
```

Use to add sth to the List:

```
texts.Add("some text");
```

Finally to place every item in the list, use a foreach loop:

```
foreach (string item in texts)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Sorry, i for answering so late. Thanks it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a list/array of the textboxes

```
myTextboxes = new []{
   textbox1,
   textbox2,
    ....
}
```

and use .Zip to combine the lists so they can be looped over:

```
foreach(var (myTextbox, myString ) in myTextboxes.Zip(myStrings){
    myTextbox.Text = myString ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code, using some `linq`.

*Assumption*

Your textboxes are directly put in Form, no other panels.

```cs
            foreach (var pair in strings.Take(14).Zip(
                this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))
            {
                pair.Second.Text = pair.First;
            }
```